# rc.local not starting when booting rasberry pi

Tags: python, linux, boot

rc local file not running when booting but when i try manuel starting it works perfectly i want to start this autamicliy on boot

sudo service rc.local status

```
● rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; static)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
           └─ttyoutput.conf
   Active: active (exited) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-01-08 22:44:22 GMT-3; 1min 4s ago
  Process: 496 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 500 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rc-local.service

Jan 08 22:44:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
Jan 08 22:44:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
Jan 08 22:44:23 raspberrypi sudo[500]: root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/sicak.py
Jan 08 22:44:23 raspberrypi sudo[500]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 08 22:44:26 raspberrypi sudo[500]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 08 22:44:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: rc-local.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Warning: Unit file changed on disk, 'systemctl daemon-reload' recommended.
```

my rc.local file

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
sudo python /home/pi/sicak.py &  <-- this not starting
exit 0
```

Comment: why do you need sudo ?  USER=root

Comment: i try both still not working

Comment: I think you should research a little more into init scripts and daemon processes . https://www.linux.com/learn/managing-linux-daemons-init-scripts You also don't need the `&`

Comment: python /home/pi/sicak.py
exit 0    im try but this not work

Answer (score 1):

`sleep 10`   <--- I add this and solved Problem

```
sudo python /home/pi/sicak.py &  <-- this not starting
exit 0
```